# incorrect navigation controller sequence results in blank navigation bar

Tags: ios, button, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am doing something wrong, but not sure what it is. Bellow is the diagram of my `storyboard`.

```
                /----(push)----login   \
Start nav ctrl                          mainview nav ctrl 
                \----(modal) register  /
```

When the user goes through login an event is received by `appdelegate` logindone, in login done I do:

```
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
```

This works just fine.

However if the user goes through register and completes registration with login the same loginDone is triggered but the code above results in blank `view`.

If I replace above code with

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
MainCtrl *mainViewController = (MainCtrl*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MainView"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController =navigationController;
```

This almost works, the view is displayed correctly, the only problem is that navigation bar is blank and it stays blank no matter where I go. Restarting app works of course because it bypasses register controller.

in register I do `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` before calling loginDone, but this really makes no difference.
Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

```
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
                                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
```

is the only thing that will work in normal flow i.e after login. Otherwise I get a crash "unavailable segue".

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this is not exactly the way I wanted to fix it, but it works. I had to modify login done function that used to handle login finish work and transition to main view passing it parameter not to transition. On return I trigger a segue to main view from registration view. Still not sure why it was not working the way I had it done originally.